# How to add 23.438 fps Audio to 29.970 fps video and achieve sync using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Been banging my head at this issue for a while now:
I have a bunch of video files with 3 streams: video, audio and subtitles. I also have same amount of separate files with 1 audio stream. I want to add separate audio stream into original video without any changes to the sources (copy), but I keep getting Non-monotous DTS in Output stream 0:0 and after I run the result through nvencc64 I get audio/video out of sync.

This is an info of the video file:

```
General
Unique ID                      : 187872679263028640844869423271293297120 (0x8D56F63D469287F5A9EE1273FE9521E0)
Complete name                  : C:\Transcoded\Призрак в доспехах Синдром одиночки\S01E01 - Public Security Section 9 – SECTION-9.mkv
Format                         : Matroska
Format version                 : Version 2
File size                      : 5.62 GiB
Duration                       : 26 min 13 s
Overall bit rate mode          : Variable
Overall bit rate               : 30.7 Mb/s
Encoded date                   : UTC 2010-02-23 11:53:20
Writing application            : mkvmerge v3.2.0 ('Beginnings') built on Feb 12 2010 16:46:17
Writing library                : libebml v0.7.9 + libmatroska v0.8.1

Video
ID                             : 1
Format                         : AVC
Format/Info                    : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                 : High@L4.1
Format settings, CABAC         : Yes
Format settings, RefFrames     : 2 frames
Muxing mode                    : Container profile=@0.0
Codec ID                       : V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC
Duration                       : 26 min 13 s
Bit rate mode                  : Variable
Width                          : 1 920 pixels
Height                         : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio           : 16:9
Frame rate mode                : Constant
Frame rate                     : 30.000 FPS
Original frame rate            : 29.970 (30000/1001) FPS
Color space                    : YUV
Chroma subsampling             : 4:2:0
Bit depth                      : 8 bits
Scan type                      : Interlaced
Scan type, store method        : Separated fields
Scan order                     : Top Field First
Default                        : No
Forced                         : No

Audio
ID                             : 2
Format                         : FLAC
Format/Info                    : Free Lossless Audio Codec
Codec ID                       : A_FLAC
Duration                       : 26 min 13 s
Bit rate mode                  : Variable
Channel(s)                     : 6 channels
Channel positions              : Front: L C R, Side: L R, LFE
Sampling rate                  : 48.0 kHz
Bit depth                      : 16 bits
Title                          : FLAC, 6 channels, 48.0 KHz, 16 bits, 1 311 Kbps
Writing library                : libFLAC 1.2.1 (UTC 2007-09-17)
Language                       : Japanese
Default                        : Yes
Forced                         : No

Text
ID                             : 3
Format                         : UTF-8
Codec ID                       : S_TEXT/UTF8
Codec ID/Info                  : UTF-8 Plain Text
Language                       : Russian
Default                        : Yes
Forced                         : Yes
```

This is info of the audio I want to add:

```
General
Unique ID                      : 228475517488211011527204318355348279908 (0xABE2C8B8BED45F1ABD41E1A38A5C5264)
Complete name                  : C:\Transcoded\Призрак в доспехах Синдром одиночки\RUS Sound [MC Entertainment]\Ghost in the Shell 01.mka
Format                         : Matroska
Format version                 : Version 2
File size                      : 51.1 MiB
Duration                       : 26 min 13 s
Overall bit rate               : 273 kb/s
Encoded date                   : UTC 2009-12-07 13:49:00
Writing application            : mkvmerge v2.9.8 ('C'est le bon') built on Aug 13 2009 12:49:06
Writing library                : libebml v0.7.7 + libmatroska v0.8.1

Audio
ID                             : 1
Format                         : AAC
Format/Info                    : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                 : HE-AACv2 / HE-AAC / LC
Codec ID                       : A_AAC
Duration                       : 26 min 13 s
Channel(s)                     : 2 channels / 6 channels / 6 channels
Channel positions              : Front: L R / Front: L C R, Side: L R, LFE / Front: L C R, Side: L R, LFE
Sampling rate                  : 48.0 kHz / 48.0 kHz / 24.0 kHz
Frame rate                     : 23.438 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode               : Lossy
Default                        : Yes
Forced                         : No
```

The problem is that the framerate of the source video file is 29.970 fps and the framerate of the audio I want to add is 23.438, thus no sync.

My script is in Powershell:

```
$Names = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Transcoded\Призрак в доспехах Синдром одиночки' -Name "*.mkv"
$Sources = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Transcoded\Призрак в доспехах Синдром одиночки\*.mkv'
$RusDub = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Transcoded\Призрак в доспехах Синдром одиночки\RUS Sound `[MC Entertainment`]\*.mka'

foreach ($e in 0..26) {ffmpeg -hwaccel cuda -analyzeduration 100000000 -probesize 100000000 -i $Sources[$e] -i $RusDub[$e] -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 0:s -map 1:a -metadata:s:a:1 language=rus -metadata:s:a:1 title="RUS Sound" -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy $Names[$e]}
```

The folder contains 26 video files and subfolder has 26 audio files.
$Names - takes name of the source file and passes it to the end.
$Sources - source video file with 3 streams.
$RusDub - the audio stream I want to add.

The script takes first Name from $Names and first MKV from $Sources with first Audio file from $RusDub

What d I need to add into my script, to make ffmpeg sync video and additional audio?

I tried -async 1 and -vsync 1 - no luck
I tried -filter:a:1 "asetpts=N/SR/TB" - no luck

Comment: Since you're copying all streams, use mkvtoolnix

Comment: I'll have a look, but will it solve the issue of out of sync video/audio due to different frame rates of video and audio sources?

Comment: Audio framerate is independent and not related to video framerate.

Comment: @Gyan - I've managed to solve the issue with mkvtoolnix, thanks.